# Android relativeLayout not matching parent in simulation but is in graphical view

Tags: android, xml

I am having troubles with my XML in Android. In the graphical layout view it looks exactly how I want it to, however when I run a simulation on a 10.1" screen it matches the parent in width but not height. When I run a simulation on my 10.1" tablet it matches neither the parents width or height. This is my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#fff">

        <!--  Header  Starts-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip">
                <!-- Logo Start-->
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
                <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Header Ends --> 
        <!-- Footer Start -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dip"
                android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Footer Ends --> 

        <!-- Registration Form -->
        <LinearLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dip"
          android:layout_below="@id/header">
          <!-- Full Name Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Full Name"/>
          <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_fullname" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
          <!--  Email Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Email"/>
          <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_email" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
          <!-- Password Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Password"/>
          <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_password" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>
          <!-- Register Button -->      
          <Button android:id="@+id/btnRegister" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Register New Account"/>
          <!-- Link to Login Screen -->
          <TextView android:id="@+id/link_to_login" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
                android:text="Have an account? Login here"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textColor="#025f7c"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Registration Form Ends -->


  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is how it is shown in graphical layout and is how I want it look,

[image]

This is how it looks on an android virtual machine 3.2 simulation,

[image]

and finally, this is how it looks on my Samsung galaxy 10.1" tablet,

[image]

can anyone see where I have gone wrong? Thank you

Comment: try : In your `manifest` use `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the 
 `android:largeScreens="true"` and `android:xlargeScreens="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the activity is calling the wrong layout .xml!

Check that your login activity has set the correct view.

```
setContentView(R.layout.thelayoutyouareusing);
```

Also, you may have set the wrong activity as the login (first) activity that starts when the app launches. Did you check your Manifest file for:

```
<activity android:name=".YourFirstActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The first activity is the one with the intent-filter portion of the code

Comment: This could be the problem. At the moment, I have an IF statement as soon as the app launches. If a cookie exists then the user is logged in and I display main.xml else I display login.xml, like so,

        if(loggedin()){
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
     // else username has not been stored, prompt login
        else{
         setContentView(R.layout.login);
        }
        
is this the problem?

Comment: is main.xml the one that looks like your second and third picture? if so then yes there is something wrong with the view that you are calling

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works then give minWidth attribute with large value to topmost parent layout tag like

```
 android:minWidth="1400dp"
```

It worked for me well and didn't create any problem even for small screen layouts